# Is there a way to change the default StartPosition on a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

The default value for `StartPosition` on Windows Forms is `WindowsDefaultLocation`, which I understand is determined by the operating system. I always have to change the value to `CenterScreen` or `CenterParent` (for modal windows) - the default location is annoying and seems to change every time. Is there a reason why `WindowsDefaultLocation` is even there or is there a way to change a setting somewhere so that the default is centered?

I don't know about everyone else, but whenever I start an application I would always prefer it to be centered, that way it's easier to work with.

Comment: Are you saying you change the property and the value isn't being kept the next time you open the designer?  Otherwise, I think most people probably prefer only to have dialog forms centered and main forms to just remember their last position on the screen.

Comment: It's there because it's the **default position** defined by the OS. No, you can't change it.

Comment: It does keep when I change it, but for every new Form I add to my application, I have to change the value every time because that is the Visual Studio default for a Form template. I'm wondering if there's a way to change the VS default to `CenterScreen` so that I don't have to change it every time I make a new form.

Comment: You can try modifying the template files "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication\"

Comment: WindowsDefaultLocation is there because programs that don't do anything to memorize their previous window location and size need it.  This is code you have to add yourself, it isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new project, Visual Studio bases it off of templates that are located in the installation directory. You can modify those templates, changing the default behavior when you create a new project.

VS2013:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication

VS2015:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication

To change the `StartUpPosition`, open the *"form1.designer.cs"* file, and add the following line to the `InitializeComponent()` method:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    ...
    ...
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
}
```

Now when you create a new `WinForms` project, the initial `Form1` that is created will have a `FormStartPosition` that's set to the center of the screen.